# Is it common to see diversity of backgrounds shown in locations where You Are So Not Invited to My Bat Mitzvah takes place?

Tags: historical-accuracy, not-invited-to-my-bat-mitzvah

It seemed the people who went to the religous school came from diverse backgrounds. Is this common? Like is it representative of the percentages that would normally occur?

For reference, [as Sarah Silverman asks here](https://youtu.be/k4sP9XjdMbs?t=207), it would seem a lack of diverse backgrounds is implied, since she felt the need to ask the question. Though there are some that maybe some consider [exceptions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Ethiopia).

Comment: Is it clear where the story is set? If so can you include that here? The location will make a big difference in terms of realism of diversity. If it’s New York City, almost any level of diversity is believable. If it’s Keokuk, Iowa, far less so.

Comment: I think anyone who has seen the movie would know that as much as I do. Or are these questions meant to provide details for those who haven't seen it?

Comment: It took place often in a religious school. I added that.

Comment: I think that there's actually a *little*  [difference](https://worldpopulationreview.com/us-cities/keokuk-ia-population) when it comes to diversity in the beautiful little town of [Keokuk, Iowa](http://www.cityofkeokuk.org/)

Comment: I guess if you only want your question answered by people who have seen the movie, then you’ve provided the appropriate level of information. Having not seen the movie, I can say that the school I go to every day is ***incredibly*** diverse. And I’ve lived in New York City and feel like almost any amount of diversity in a story set there is believable and realistic. So I don’t feel like I need to see the movie to give you useful information on its realism, but perhaps you disagree and that’s ok.

Comment: I wouldn't want to fully explain for people who haven't seen the movie.

Comment: Why would you not want to fully explain?  The more people who can answer your 'historical accuracy' question the better.  Are you concerned about spoilers?  No-one concerned with getting spoiled should be digging through comments on a question, or even opening the question in the first place.

Comment: I would not want to fully explain because of the possible sensitivity of the topic. I'm just curious and don't want to invite debate from undesirable elements, so to speak. People who actually watched the movie may be more interested without ulterior motives.

Comment: This Q isn't about the movie, but rather about real life. You won't get proper answers without explaining. Religious school diversity is about context: in the city of Philadelphia, many, if not most kids who attend Catholic School are not catholic. And Quaker schools are the main choice outside of public schools.

Comment: It's about the accuracy of what is depicted in the movie, it's totally about the movie. I don't think there is much to explain for people who have seen the movie.

Comment: Is it really a thing here to explain things to people who haven't seen the movie?

Answer (score 1):

Some numbers are known for ([public](https://nces.ed.gov/programs/coe/indicator/cge/racial-ethnic-enrollment) or [private](https://nces.ed.gov/fastfacts/display.asp?id=55)) schools or cities, some aren't. Are numbers accurate? Hard to say, because they differ from location to location. Does it matter? Not that much. What you want to do, when making such a book/movie, is to show as many different backgrounds as possible. You want to talk to people from all sensibilities. So, you create as many different characters and personalities as possible/needed and you make them discover each other, and different attitudes create funny situations sometimes. It's way to work for inclusion and better understanding of the other culture/background.

> it was also important for the stars to embrace each other’s cultures and display them in the film. It makes such an impact if people know about other people’s traditions because it just brings everyone closer together. [J-14 interviews](https://www.j-14.com/posts/you-are-so-not-invited-to-my-bat-mitzvah-stars-talk-book-movie/)

It's also why they wanted to show many different Jewish characters, because many people involved in the writing/making had different experience.

> they also care deeply about authenticity — and giving teens fun, entertaining and diverse representation. [...] And there’s all walks of life and different socio-economic statuses. [Director's interview](https://www.kveller.com/the-director-of-you-are-so-not-invited-to-my-bat-mitzvah-wanted-to-make-an-authentically-jewish-film/)

Sammi’s hope was that the Jewish theme would resonate with viewers, regardless of their religious affiliation.

> “It's about educating the world in a gentle way that invites you in as one member of the party. It's not forceful, it's just giving you insight. It's very much a human story. And I think people forget that we're all human beings and we're all so deeply similar. The dressing might be different, but the heart is so similar, you know?” “We've shown the movie to some small audiences now, a lot of whom aren't Jewish, and what I'm hearing in those theaters and screenings are things like, ‘oh, we have something just like that!’ ‘Oh, my God, that's cool!’ ‘Oh my god, this is so fun, I want this!’ I really wanted to get behind a movement that showcases how we're similar and how we're all human beings.” [Director's interview](https://aish.com/you-are-so-not-invited-to-my-bat-mitzvah-interview-with-the-director/)

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like a conscious decision. But was it a public school?

Comment: You mean the religious school ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you linked to public school info.

Comment: My mistake, misclick and copied wrong link first, fixed it with both numbers